# Select a record from given month and year

Tags: php, database

Select a record from given year and month. I am doing like this

```
if ($_REQUEST['thismonth']!=''){

         $fromdate = $_REQUEST['thismonth']."-01 00:00:00";

         $todate = $_REQUEST['thismonth']."-31 23:59:59";

        $fdate=explode('-',$fromdate);
        //print_r($fdate);

         $year1=$fdate[0];
        $month1=$fdate[1];
        $date = $year1=$fdate[0]."-".$month1=$fdate[1];

$result=mysql_query("select * from tbl_daily_rpt where date like '%$date%' order by cdate desc");

    }
```

and date format in tbl_daily_rpt table like this way **2017-02-28**. when echo a $date value is given a **2017-02**. Select all the records which date like this **2017-02**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why don't you instead opt to use the MYSQL functions for part of this? `SELECT * FROM tbl_daily_rpt WHERE MONTH(date) = ? AND YEAR(date) = ?`

Comment: My question is that how to fetch a record from table where year and month like this  2017-02

Comment: By the way, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) because atm you're putting everything at risk

Comment: But date format in table like this 2017-02-28 how to fetch a record from it.?

Comment: @Arslan Check my answer and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_daily_rpt where YEAR(`date`) = '2017' AND MONTH(`date`) = '02'
```